# How to read a text file which contain multiple json data and which divide by the unice separator. in android kotlin

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, kotlin

*** My the target work is the read the text file line by line using readline() function and then when came to the separator then send 1st JSON to the JSON parser...

1st I will share text file screen short : - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USS8a.png)
This screen short, you will see the red mark which is the used separator.

but my problem is that when I read the text file from the assets folder and read it line by line using a stream reader and separate the separator they can not get the proper data.

I will share the code what I will do

```
private fun loadJSONFromAsset(){
        //function to load the JSON from the Asset and return the object
        var data: String? = null
        try {
            val jsonFileLoad = assets.open("json.txt")
            val inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(jsonFileLoad)
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            var str : String
             while ( bufferedReader.readLine().also { str = it } != null){
                if (str != "|"){
                    stringBuilder.append(str)
                } else {
                    data = stringBuilder.toString()
                    stringBuilder.delete(0, stringBuilder.length)
                }
                Log.e(TAG, ""+data)
            }
            jsonFileLoad.close()
        } catch (ex : IOException){
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return data
    }
```

#### this the new code and it return in log it null

this is my file read function which read the file but can not separate

#### i also  send the error image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVcLI.png)

Comment: What output you are getting right now?

Comment: it returns the total text file data, but I also some changes in my code, but the can not give the proper error. I will share the code

Comment: Check your return statement.

Comment: I can not send the code in the comment section. BUT i will write a new how to send you. plz share your email

Comment: Update your question. See your are returning a variable name `string` where it is in the code?

Comment: i will update my question

Comment: your jsonFileLoad is null